# How much, if any, does resolution effect the net power consumption of watching online video?

Tags: energy-efficiency, electricity, carbon-footprint, alternatives, internet

I watch a lot of online video. I'd assume that for example videos on Youtube in 720p use less power than the same videos in 1080p. I think this might be because:

- more power is used by sending network to read more data and then send it
- more power is used by intermediate network (internet) to transfer more data
- more power is used on my end to recieve data
- more power is used on my end to actually render the video

However, I have nothing to back up my theory. I've heard the [most likely incorrect rumour](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/a/5584/99) that one Google search uses the equivalent of boiling one litre of water, so I'm guessing it might be significant.

Is there a difference? How much?

Comment: Interesting question! BTW the rumour that a [two Google Searches requires the equivalent of boiling one litre of water](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/google/4217055/Two-Google-searches-produce-same-CO2-as-boiling-a-kettle.html) is most likely incorrect (see also [my answer on How much CO2 do I cause with one Google search?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/a/5584/99)).

Comment: Just saw an interesting piece on YouTube's energy consumption from researchers at the University of Bristol: ["Simple Design Changes Could Make YouTube Better for the Planet, Researchers Say"](https://earther.gizmodo.com/simple-design-changes-could-make-youtube-better-for-the-1834581507).

Comment: There's been an increase in use of streaming video services during the COVID-19 crisis, and the International Energy Agency published an interesting blog post on the energy implications: [The carbon footprint of streaming video: fact-checking the headlines](https://www.iea.org/commentaries/the-carbon-footprint-of-streaming-video-fact-checking-the-headlines)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Natural Resources Defense Council commissioned a study in late 2015 to understand the energy consumption from 4K TVs, titled *[The Big Picture: Ultra High-Definition Televisions Could Add $1 Billion to Viewers' Annual Electric Bills](https://www.nrdc.org/resources/big-picture-ultra-high-definition-televisions-could-add-1-billion-viewers-annual-electric)*. While this doesn't *exactly* answer your question as regards the resolution of You-Tube videos, it gives some solid clues.

First of all, the study finds that **"UHD televisions use an average of 30 percent more power than HD televisions of a similar size."** This finding is illustrated in Figure 9 from the report:

[image]

So this means that if you have an HD or UHD capable screen, you are likely using more power than a screen which is not capable of showing higher resolution video.

Next, the authors compared energy consumption on the same TVs for HD vs 4K content: **"Feeding a 4K television, a higher-resolution (4K) version of HD video material did tend to increase energy use by an average of 10 percent, but there were large differences between models."** Figure 16 illustrates this:

[image]

Thus, it seems that when you are viewing higher resolution video you will indeed be consuming more energy, but the exact difference varies significantly by model.

Finally, the authors find a bit of a silver lining: **"Meanwhile, streaming higher-resolution content via the Internet instead of playing it from a disc did not make a significant difference in energy use, which is good news as people increasingly stream content over the Internet."**

Comment: Thanks! Very good answer, but I'll keep this as open for a while if anyone manages to find any kind of equivalent data from the platform or infrastructure side and also information specifically about computers and computer monitors.